Unable to establish Remote connection with Keithley 2230g 3Ch DC Power supply from Canoe Tool via rs232
I am trying to control a power source with CANoe through RS232 Serial Communication, however when I send a command to the power source using the built in rs232Send function, no response from the Power Supply.
This is my first time trying it out. So not sure what I'm missing out here.
Power supply used -> Keithley 2230g-30-6 3Channel DC power supply.
Canoe version used is 18.0
The connection to the COM Port is successful from the CANoe. But when I try sending the SCPI command "SYSTem:REMote", which is command to activate the remote connection to Keithley Power supply, no response is received.
Please find the below screenshot to see the connection to COM port is successful.
Serial Port connected.
Code for the above screenshot.
InitSerialPort()
{
  // close serial port (port may have changed, former port shall not remain open)
  if(Rs232Close(getValue(EnvPortA))==1)
    writeLineEx(0,kINFO, "Serial port %d successfully closed.", getValue(EnvPortA));    
  else
    writeLineEx(0,kERROR,"An error occurred during closing of the serial port %d.", getValue(EnvPortA));    

  // set state (close aborts all open requests)
  gSending = 0;

  // open the serial port (comes up with Windows defaults)
  if(Rs232Open(getValue(EnvPortA))==1)
    writeLineEx(0,kINFO, "Serial port %d successfully opened.", getValue(EnvPortA));    
  else
    writeLineEx(0,kERROR,"An error occurred during opening of the serial port %d.", getValue(EnvPortA));    

  // configure the serial port
  // - just take the panel content
  if(Rs232Configure(getValue(EnvPortA),getValue(EnvBitPerSecondsPortA),getValue(EnvDataBitsPortA),getValue(EnvStopbitsPortA),getValue(EnvParityPortA))==1)
    writeLineEx(0,kINFO, "Serial port %d successfully initialized.", getValue(EnvPortA));    
  else
    writeLineEx(0,kERROR,"An error occurred during initialization of the serial port %d.", getValue(EnvPortA));    
  
  if(Rs232SetHandshake(getValue(EnvPortA), kHANDSHAKE_DISABLED, 0, 0, 0, 0))
    writeLineEx(0,kINFO, "Handshake parameters for serial port %d successfully configured.", getValue(EnvPortA));    
  else
    writeLineEx(0,kERROR,"An error occurred during the serial port %d configuration of handshake parameters.", getValue(EnvPortA));

  // set buffer for reception (otherwise callback would not work)
  if(Rs232Receive(getValue(EnvPortA), gReceiverCallbackBuffer, kBUFFER_SIZE))
    writeLineEx(0,kINFO, "Receiver buffer for serial port %d successfully set.", getValue(EnvPortA));    
  else
    writeLineEx(0,kERROR,"An error occurred during setting the receiver buffer for serial port %d.", getValue(EnvPortA));
}

I have added Res232onSend and RS232OnError to confirm the connection.
RS232OnSend( dword port, byte buffer[], dword number )
{
  // set state
  gSending = 0;

  writeLineEx(0,kINFO,"Transmission of %d bytes from port %d completed !", number, port);
}

RS232OnError( dword port, dword errorFlags )
{
  // set state
  gSending = 0;

  writeLineEx(0,kERROR,"Error handler called with error code %d !", errorFlags);

  if ( errorFlags & 1 )
    writeLineEx(0,1,"%d informs of send error",errorFlags);
  if ( errorFlags & 2 )
    writeLineEx(0,1,"%d informs of receive error",errorFlags);
  if ( errorFlags & 4 )
    writeLineEx(0,1,"%d informs of frame error",errorFlags);
  if ( errorFlags & 8 )
    writeLineEx(0,1,"%d informs of parity error",errorFlags);
  if ( errorFlags & 16 )
    writeLineEx(0,1,"%d informs of overrun error",errorFlags);
  if ( errorFlags & 32 )
    writeLineEx(0,1,"%d informs of receiver overrun error",errorFlags);
  if ( errorFlags & 64 )
    writeLineEx(0,1,"%d informs of break state",errorFlags);
  if ( errorFlags & 128 )
    writeLineEx(0,1,"%d informs of send timeout error",errorFlags);
}

No errors were received.
Below function is to send the SCPI command.
on timer Start_Cmd_Timer
{
  strncpy(SReceiverBuffer,"",10);
  
  snprintf(Start_Command, elcount(Start_Command),"SYST:REM");
      if ( 1==SendData(Start_Command) )
     {
       write("Connection req sent");
      }
    else
      {
        write("Connection issue- Not ON");
        }
}

Serial transmission.

Most likely something wrong in SendData
